# Involutions on semisimple Banach algebras are continuous

Tags: banach-algebras, involutions

Let $A$ be a semisimple Banach algebra, $ x \mapsto x^{*} $ be an involution on $A$. Then it is continuous.

I've looked through some reference books and webpages, all of them prove this by using closed graph theorem, or the fact that every homomorphism from a Banach algebra onto a semisimple Banach algebra is continuous (some call this Johnson's Theorem) (eg. this post: [Does *-operator be automatically continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370452/does-operator-be-automatically-continuous/370561#370561)) However both of these theorems require the mapping under consideration to be linear, while an involution is anti-linear by definition; in particular $( \lambda x)^{*}=\bar{\lambda}x^{*} \neq \lambda x^{*}$ in general.

Am I missing something here as to why these methods of proof are right? Can someone supply me with a correct proof if the proofs are wrong? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the point that there is some sloppiness when people deal with complex scalars. This case can be rectified however quite easily.

Apply any of these theorems to the [complex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_vector_space) of $A$ (which is still a semi-simple Banach algebra). Then the involution is linear on it.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!